# Картинка вместо стандартного кружка в input radio

Tags: html, css

Гуглил долго и нудно, нашел один пример, но такой запутанный и сложный, что бросил его.
Подскажите, как вместо стандартного кружка с точкой поставить свою картинку?

Comment: Пишите свою реализацию. Их же браузеры рисуют, каждый по-своему. Мож кто пример на jquery подкинет, я в нем не силен, а на "чистом" js это довольно муторно. Ну и собственно <a href="http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/">вот</a>, например.

Comment: Отчего же на чистом JS муторно то? О_о

Comment: присмотритесь к решению по ссылке от Sh4dow, селекты там реализованы плохо, а вот чекбоксы и радио баттоны работают прекрасно, использовал их неоднократно.

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну я имею в виду *хорошее* решение. Типа добавления в `<head>` скрипта одной строкой, который заменит все нужные поля на свои (замена radio на hidden, следом добавление div и навешивание на него действий и стилей). На jquery это явно красивее, быстрее и надежнее.

Comment: @Андрей Стифурак, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается через `<input type="image" src="noactive.gif" />`, при клике заменяется `src="active.gif"`, картинки рисовать какие хочется уже.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com это именно то, что тебе надо